# Symfony Custom error message

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling

I have a login form which uses the Symfony security system.

I would now like to customise the error messages for example if you enter invalid credentials Symfony returns 'Bad Credentials'. How could I customise that message to something like 'Invalid email/password'?

Comment: grrr why is Smyfony so un-customisable, surly it should be made really easy to alter the login error messages :(

Comment: Indeed is deeply customizable ... but this one has been forgotten in the first version. This is a well known problem that should have been fixed in Symfony 2.1, did it ?

Answer (score 1):

For this one, and only for this one, this is not a validation error, but an Exception message that is badly sent to controller...

If I well remember, you can override it in a `messages.yml` file (with .yml or .xliff extension, as you want) :

```
"Bad credentials": "Invalid email/password"
```

This is really ugly but it's the only way to achieve this for login error. Same fix for "The presented password cannot be empty" or "The presented password is invalid"...

And, in the Twig template, you have to apply translator :

```
{% if error %}
    <p class="error">{{ error.message|trans }}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you using FOSUserBundle?  If so, all messages are stored in translation files.

Copy the translation files from FOSUserBundle\Resources\translations to your UserBundle that overrides FOSUserBundle.

Symfony is HIGHLY customisable, as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: Why aren't you using FOSUserBundle?

Comment: @Mike A lot of us like to figure out how to do it *without* help first, and then understand *why* the 'help' is useful. Same goes for frameworks - learn PHP first, understand why you need a framework, then take on a framework for the reasons you require. Consider it research.